# How to instantiate an IPAD or OPAD in Vivado

Tags: vhdl, vivado

In old Xilinx Synthesis Tool (XST) from [xilinx-ise](/questions/tagged/xilinx-ise), it was possible to manually instantiate an `IPAD` or `OPAD` primitive directly in the design. It allowed designers to hide ports from being exposed to the top-level.

In XST, the `*PAD` instances where unbound components and considered black-boxes. Even `translate` complained about a black-box. But then, `map` magically recognized the components and was happy, so place & route was successful. Even the pad location could be specified with VHDL attributes hiding the need for UCF files. Not that I used that feature after testing, but it worked!

**How can I achieve this in Vivado?**

I created a similar example as I used for Xilinx ISE. In Xilinx Vivado I get the following warning:

> [Project 1-486] Could not resolve non-primitive black box cell 'OutPad' instantiated as 'OPad' ["C:/Temp/IOBuffer/src/top.vhd":63]

This is my test code:

```
library IEEE;
use     IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

library UniSim;
use     UniSim.VComponents.all;

entity top is
    port (
        AC701_SystemClock_200MHz_p   : in  std_logic;
        AC701_SystemClock_200MHz_n   : in  std_logic;
        AC701_GPIO_Button_CPU_Reset  : in  std_logic;
        AC701_GPIO_LED               : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of top is
    attribute DONT_TOUCH : boolean;
    attribute BLACK_BOX  : string;

    signal AC701_SystemClock_200MHz : std_logic;
    signal SystemClock_200MHz       : std_logic;

    signal DataIn       : std_logic;
    signal DataOut      : std_logic := '0';
    signal DataInternal : std_logic := '0';
    signal DataToPad    : std_logic;

    component OPAD is
        port (
            Pad : in std_logic
        );
    end component;

    attribute DONT_TOUCH of DataToPad   : signal is FALSE;
    attribute DONT_TOUCH of OPAD        : component is FALSE;
    attribute BLACK_BOX  of OPAD      : component is "YES";
begin
    BufDS: IBUFDS
        port map (
            I  => AC701_SystemClock_200MHz_p,
            IB => AC701_SystemClock_200MHz_n,
            O  => AC701_SystemClock_200MHz
        );

    ClkBuf: BUFG
        port map (
            I => AC701_SystemClock_200MHz,
            O => SystemClock_200MHz
        );

    DataIn       <= AC701_GPIO_Button_CPU_Reset;
    DataOut      <= DataIn                  when rising_edge(SystemClock_200MHz);
    DataInternal <= DataInternal xor DataIn when rising_edge(SystemClock_200MHz);

    AC701_GPIO_LED <= (others => DataOut);

    Buf: OBuf
        port map (
            I => DataInternal,
            O => DataToPad
        );

    OutPad: OPAD
        port map (
            Pad => DataToPad
        );
end architecture;
```

Comment: I've never understood why you would instantiate single-ended IO buffers at all. There doesn't seem to be anything similar to `OPAD` in the language templates. I suppose I'm asking if this is in fact an XY question.

Comment: The single-ended buffer is an example. I'm would like to hide complex interfaces like 4 times DDR4. These are fixed in the design and always present. See my extended explanation for XST. It's not an XY question, because I'm investigation the possibilities/power of Vivado. I know that the discovered solution could be a solution for some problems. My goal is to test if the old solution for XST might still be an option to solve problems in the same way with Vivado.

Comment: You contradict yourself: it in fact is a XY problem, because in the end you want to do something different ;) But anyhow, I think nowadays you only instantiate `IBUF` and `OBUF` and such... No mention of `xPAD` in UG953. I don't think it's allowed to hide system I/O ports from the top level any more.